# Discourage the word "confusion" in question titles, or encourage the use of "How to"

Tags: discussion, questions, title, wording

Recently I've observed a lot of questions using the word "confusion" in the title. There is even a **[[confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/confusion)]** tag.
There is nothing wrong if a person is confused about the usage of some API/concept/etc, and there are not that many questions with this in the title, but:

- it doesn't add information to the question title
- it is not helping when others google for the same thing

Could there be some sort of discouragement, or better, encouragement of using "How to" or "Why"?

This will effectively make the question title much clearer. When the author of the question is encouraged to think for a sentence starting with "How to", he'll produce a better title.

Examples:

- "Confusion about interfaces" -> "How to make partial implementations of an interface"
- "Confusion about cloning" -> "Why the MemberwiseClone works for all my objects"

Comment: Maybe they just love their New Order.

Comment: ...and ban "howto" without a space -- http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22howto%22 (For questions, that is; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"How to" doesn't add information to the title either. Better to construct a question title that really nuggets the gold out of the post.

> #### Okay:
>
> "How to make partial implementations of an interface"
>
> #### Better:
>
> Creating partial implementations of an interface

There are plenty of users over 2k rep that can come along and fix up the posts. You're not ever going to programatically stop people from asking poor questions. They just either won't or don't know how to.

Plus, they exist to help other users get their [Strunk & White badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white).

And if you did have some kind of bot, it would probably be suspended/flagged over and over again because people enjoy making those who can read English weep at poor sentence structure. As they are wont to do.

Comment: Do those quotes in the "Okay" example have any special meaning? ;-)

Comment: fair points indeed.

Comment: Those quotes point out the fact that what spills out isn't really a "how to". Like when you're asking about moving the turtle in logo. @arj